# Ext JS DisplayField how to change dynamically loaded value

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, extjs

I have this DisplayField that is loading dynamically while program is running. It's loading with date value with format 'Ymd'(without seperators), what I want is to change date's format to 'd.m.Y' after it's loaded.

Now, I have a base DisplayField class and I extend it in my program. I want to format the value with an event on my base class. I was able to format the value with change event but it causes an another change event so on then in to a loop. I used another counter variable to prevent the loop but is there an another way to do it much cleaner way?

**My Display Field:**

```
Ext.define('MyDisplayField', {
extend: 'Ext.form.DisplayField',
enableDateFormat: false,
dateFormat: GlobalConfigProperties.dateFormat, 
counter : 0,
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        listeners: {
            change: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                if(field.enableDateFormat && field.counter == 0) {
                    field.counter = 1;
                    var date = Ext.Date.parse(newValue, 'Ymd');
                    field.setValue(Ext.Date.format(date, field.dateFormat));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [setRawValue](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Display-method-setRawValue), it should bypass change detection.